# How can I prevent an image from appearing in table view section header cell when it is not set

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a table view with section cells and one cell in each section to display an image when the section cell is clicked on. Upon first click there is no image in the section header cell (which is the expected behavior). But when I click on it a secong time the image appears in the section header cell. I am not sure why this is happening and how to prevent it.
Here is the code where I deal with any images and set the images for specific cells.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm4ng.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGsBA.png)

```
import UIKit

class expandedSection {
    let title: String
    var isOpened: Bool = false
    var image: UIImage!
    init(title: String,
         isOpened: Bool = false, image: UIImage) {
        self.title = title
        self.isOpened = isOpened
        self.image = image
    }
}

class AnalyticsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    /*
     
        Variables
     
    
     */
    
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var sectionImages = [UIImage(named: "graph1"), UIImage(named: "graph1")]
    private var sections = [expandedSection]()
    /*
     
        Constructor
     
    
     */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // set up models
        
        sections.insert(expandedSection(title: "Title", image: sectionImages[0]!), at: 0)

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 127/255, green: 204/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1)
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "ExercisesTableViewCell", bundle: .main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExercisesTableViewCell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        self.navigationItem.title = "Progression"
    }
    
    /*
     
        TableView Initializers - Legs
     

     */
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let section = sections[section]
        // creates number of rows in sections based off the options array length + 1 (to account for the section header)
        if section.isOpened {
            return 2
        }
        else {
            return 1
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: ExercisesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExercisesTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ExercisesTableViewCell
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].title
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 73/255, green: 72/255, blue: 178/255, alpha: 1)
            
        }
        else {
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.textLabel?.text = ""
            cell.imageView?.image = sections[indexPath.section].image
            cell.imageView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row != 0 {
            return 400.0
        }
        else {
            return 50
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            sections[indexPath.section].isOpened = !sections[indexPath.section].isOpened
            tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have tried specifically setting the image to hidden on those cells but that still results in the text in the section headers moveing to the right to accomodate for space.

Comment: So we can help you, could you ensure your code is formatted nicely? Could you also provide all related code - for example, you mention the issue is related to clicks but the code that handles clicks is not shown in your snippet. Thanks :)

Comment: How do you define number of section and number of row in section ? What I see is that your section should have 2 rows ?

Comment: @SeanAnglim Added the code to handle to click func didSelectRowAt

Comment: @PtitXav yes the first row (index 0) is the section and has the textlabels. The second row (index 1) has the image

Comment: Could you post all relevant code? There is still a lot of code missing making it difficult to help.

Comment: @SeanAnglim, this is the entire file minus some button creation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a layout issue as the `UITableView` code you've posted, while rather messy, looks to be logically sound.

I suggest that you use the built-in iOS table view section headers as it is designed to handle what you're looking to do. As a starting point, have a look at the [viewForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) docs.